# Type Error: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

This works

```
console.log(comments[i].includes("NEW ENTRY"));
```

This doesn't work

```
while ((comments[i].includes("NEW ENTRY")) == false) {

//Some code

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet to reproduce the problem. Your example code is to limited to find the error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the little information you give us, I would say that you do not manage the incrementation of your variable **i**.

```
const arrStr = ["hello", "asdf", "dfa"]
arrStr[0].includes("hel") // -> true
arrStr[1].includes("hel") // -> false
arrStr[2].includes("hel") // -> false
arrStr[3].includes("hel") // -> cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

If you look at the DCR's answers you will see how to manage the incrementation

Answer (score 0):

both work just fine! It's likely that your i counter is wrong.

```js
var comments=['try a little harder','NEW ENTRY',"another test"];

console.log(comments[1].includes("NEW ENTRY"));

var i = 0;
while ((comments[i].includes("NEW ENTRY")) == false) {
console.log(comments[i]);
i++;}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: comments of code are harder to read